# Change level nodes positions in a treeview

Tags: vb.net, treeview, move, nodes, levels

For a few days now, I've been dealing with a problem with TreeViews on **VB.net**.
I have an application that has a treeview with a hierarchy that goes like this:

```
Node 1
     |--- Node 2
          |--- Node 3
               |--- Node 4
```

Meaning that every node only has a child and the whole treeview only has a root.
What I'm trying to accomplish is, by using 'Move Up' and 'Move Down' buttons, to switch these nodes position. Suppose I'd like to move 'Node 2' up, it would take the 'Node 1' place and 'Node 1' would go to the 'Node 2' position.

I've tried a few things, but could never get it to work, so what I did was change only the properties of these nodes (Text, ToolTipText, ...).
I would like to be able to do this by actually moving the nodes, not only to make it look 'right', but also to learn a few more things about this control, because, to me, it is a bit confusing to deal with (I'm new on the .Net development)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Anyway, I ended up being forced to use another Control, which means that my question didn't make sense anymore.
Since I'm new here, can you tell if it is wrong to (if possible) accept both answers?

Answer (score 0):

To make Node 2 as the parent of Node 1:

```
TreeView1.Nodes("Node1").Parent = TreeView1.Nodes("Node2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote some code to give you a direction (**untested**):

```
Enum Directions
    Up
    Down
End Enum

Public Sub MoveNode(ByVal nodeToBeMoved As Windows.Forms.TreeNode, ByVal direction As Directions)
    Dim parent As TreeNode = nodeToBeMoved.Parent
    If parent Is Nothing AndAlso
        direction = Directions.Up Then
        MsgBox("Node cannot be moved up!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim child As TreeNode = nodeToBeMoved.FirstNode
    If child Is Nothing AndAlso
        direction = Directions.Down Then
        MsgBox("Node cannot be moved down!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim childFirstNode As TreeNode = child.FirstNode

    nodeToBeMoved.Nodes.Clear()
    If direction = Directions.Up Then
        parent.Nodes.Clear()
        nodeToBeMoved.Nodes.Add(parent)
        parent.Nodes.Add(child)
    Else
        child.Nodes.Clear()
        child.Nodes.Add(nodeToBeMoved)
        nodeToBeMoved.Nodes.Add(childFirstNode)
    End If
End Sub
```